# What does 'null?', 'procedure?' and 'symbol?' mean in the following code?

Tags: python, lisp

I am going through the following documentation for implementing a Lisp Interpreter in Python: http://norvig.com/lispy.html

In the **standard_env** function, a dictionary has been defined for mapping certain symbols or variables to their corresponding functions or values. However, I am not being able to understand the following entries in the **env** dictionary:

```
env = {}
env.update({
    'equal?':  op.eq, 
    'list?':   lambda x: isinstance(x,list),
    'null?':   lambda x: x == [], 
    'number?': lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float)),   
    'procedure?': callable,
    'symbol?': lambda x: isinstance(x, str),
})
```

What does the '?' at the end of the key mean? Could you please provide some examples where these entries will be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntactically `?` is just one of the many characters allowed in identifiers in Lisp. So it's simply part of the function name.

By convention function names ending in `?` are used for functions that return boolean values.

Specifically `equal?` checks whether its two arguments are equal, `null?` checks whether its argument is an empty list and all the other ones are type checks, i.e. they check whether their argument is of the given type.

> Could you please provide some examples where these entries will be used?

Functions returning booleans are most often used in `if` or `cond` conditions, so you might see something like this as an example of a function using `null?`:

```
(define (sum lst)
  (if (null? lst)
    0
    (+ (first lst) (sum (rest lst)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Lisp, but looking at the definitions of these terms, this looks like these are being used to check what the parameters are, i.e. 'list?' maps to a function that tests if the parameter is a list, 'procedure?' tests if the parameter is a procedure (or at least is callable), 'null?' tests for an empty list (perhaps this is how nulls are represented in the interpreter), etc.

Answer (score 1):

In most Lisp dialects, identifiers (actually, [symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_(programming)) names) can contain punctuation like `?` (or `!` or `-`)

Conventionally, in Scheme, *predicate* names (naming functions returning a testable boolean) have their name ending with `?` (for example [`list?`](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/)), and side effecting functions have their name ending with `!` (for example `vector-set!`); see also [R5RS](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/) and [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/).

In Common Lisp, [predicate](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_p.htm) names often end with `P` (e.g. [`listp`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_listp.htm#listp))

These naming conventions are just useful conventions. You could name your function `foo!bar?x` even if it is not a predicate.